# Blender is not rendering the specific object the way I modeled it

Tags: modeling, rendering

I made a simple PC rig model with Blender, however, when it is rendered, the box isn't rendered the way I modeled it - it goes down bit or something. The first pic is the model rendered in cycles engine in preview, and second is the fully rendered one.
Please, can someone tell me why it works in this way?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of the modifier stack of this object ?

Comment: Based on the triangulated shading, my guess is you used a boolean modifier to add the front I/O connectors. Booleans often leave ugly topology that needs further reworking, and can be responsible for shading artifacts among other things.

Comment: I made a new model, and it is fixed. There was nothing in the modifier stack btw, strange. Anyway, thank you.